# Store "mobilePhone" in contact info during registration - Azure AD B2C Custom policy + MFA

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How to store mobile Phone Number during SignUp/Registration with MFA in Azure AD B2C Custom Policies.
What is the claim name that we can use to refer to mobile Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and store a mobile phone by using the "mobile" attribute [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes).

To actually implement this you would need to follow the steps in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). For example, the linked code adds a "city" claim, you would need to replace "city" with "mobile"

```
<!-- 
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsSchema> -->
    <ClaimType Id="mobile">
      <DisplayName>Mobile Phone</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
      <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
  <!-- 
  </ClaimsSchema>
</BuildingBlocks>-->
```